# I'm using a code in pine editor in TRADING VIEW for algo trading but it is sending both the signals at the same time

Tags: pine-script

This is my custom code and it is sending 1 and -1 i.e (buy ce/ square off pe) and (buy pe/ square off ce ) but is sending out both signals at the same time as you can see in the log alert.

Could you please help me out with a solution or any change that can be done ?

Also I'm using TRADETRON as a bridge to execute algo generated trade in angel broking but as two signals are being generated at the same time it took the right position in my personal account but the oppsosite in the subscriber's account could you please fix this problem so that we can get on with our trading careers under your guidance.

Best Regards

Chanchal

Comment: Did you forget to add your code and some screenshots?

Comment: yes sir, where can I send those ??

Comment: Edit your question and use the appropiate buttons to add a code sample and an image.

Comment: sir it is not letting me add multiple images and code can we please contact on email?

Comment: as you need 10 reputations to post images and code , I'm a new user hence not being able to

Answer (score 0):

i think you have enabled recalculate after order is filled.or you may try this code - `alert.freq_once_per_bar_close`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).